# Probability of 200 people playing

Tags: probability

In a certain game, a player rolls a coin onto a board with coloured squares, which are either red, blue, green or yellow. If the coin lands entirely within one of these coloured squares the player wins a prize; otherwise, the player loses.

The probabilities of coin landing on each of the coloured squares are respectively $\mathbb{P}(\textrm{Red})=0.15$, $\mathbb{P}(\textrm{Blue})=0.09$, $\mathbb{P}(\textrm{Green})=0.05$, and $\mathbb{P}(\textrm{Yellow})=0.06$. The probability the player loses is $\mathbb{P}(\textrm{Lose})=0.65$.

**1.** One day $200$ people play this game. Approximately how many would you expect to win a prize?

Ok, I know this seems so easy but this was my solution which is probably totally wrong. I guessed that the probabilities above were for one person. First, I added $\mathbb{P}(\textrm{Red})$, $\mathbb{P}(\textrm{Blue})$, $\mathbb{P}(\textrm{Green})$ and $\mathbb{P}(\textrm{Yellow})$ together as that's the chance of winning, i.e. $0.09 + 0.15 + 0.05 + 0.06 = 0.2$. Then, I multiplied that by $200$ to get $40$. Lastly, I took that off from $200$ to obtain $=160$.

I was wondering, is there any way of working it out easier?

**2.** It costs $80$p to play the game once. The prize for winning is $£2$. If the $200$ people play the game once, approximately how much profit do you expect the game to make?

I know how to go from there but it's only if **1.** is right.

Answer (score 1):

For question 1, we would expect that $0.2 \times 200 = 40$ of the 200 players will win. If you subtract $40$ from $200$, you are calculating the number of people who can expect to *lose.*

Comment: Note: OP added the four probabilities incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

$0.09 + 0.15 + 0.05 + 0.06 = 0.35$ not $0.2$.

Note that $0.35+0.65=1$ as you would hope, since the total probability should be $1$.

So you should have done the calculation $200 \times 0.35=70$ as the expected number of winners.  This answers the question *"Approximately how many would you expect to win a prize?"*.

You would subtract this from $200$ to get the expected number of losers, so $200-70=130$.  As an alternative approach, $200 \times 0.65 =130$ gives the same expected number of losers.